# Make post call if text box content has not changed for X seconds

Tags: jquery

I have the following code block that sends the contents of a text input with id `searchBox` to a server using jQuery.

```
$(document).ready(function () {    
  $('#searchBox').on('input', function () {
    var searchContent = $(this).val()


    if (searchContent.length == 0) {
      // other not relevant code
    }
    else {    
   

        $.post('/checkAvailability',
          { domainName: searchContent },
          function (data, status, jqXHR) {
            console.log(status + ' ' + data);
          });

    }
  });
});
```

How can I call the `$.post` function only if the search content has not changed for 3 seconds?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Without using another implementation like `lodash.throttle` or `lodash.debounce`, you could use `setTimeout` and `clearTimeout`.

(I commented out the call to `$.post` and just used a `console.log()` call for the demo)

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  let run;

  $("#searchBox").on("input", function() {
    const searchContent = $(this).val();
    clearTimeout(run);

    if (searchContent.length == 0) {
      // other not relevant code
    } else {
      run = setTimeout(() => {
        console.log(searchContent);
        /* $.post(
          "/checkAvailability", {
            domainName: searchContent
          },
          function(data, status, jqXHR) {
            console.log(status + " " + data);
          }
        ); */
      }, 3000);
    }
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input id="searchBox" />
```